# Where is the mistake in my proof of $\lim_{x \to 0} f(|x|)=l \implies \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=l$?

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification

Assume that $f:(-a,a) \setminus{0} \to \mathbb{R}$. Does the implication $\lim_{x \to 0} f(|x|) =l \implies \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=l$ hold?

My textbook gives a counter-example of this statement using the example $f(x)=[|x|]$; before finding out a counter-example myself, I've tried to prove this and made a proof that is of course wrong (so I naively stopped searching for counter-examples; bad behaviour). However, I would like to learn from my mistake and identify where is my wrong reasoning. Can someone help me find where the mistake is?

Wrong proof: by hypothesis $\lim_{x \to 0} f(|x|)=l$, so it is true that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $x\in(-a,a)\setminus{0}$, $|x|<\delta(\varepsilon)\implies |f(|x|)-l|<\epsilon$.

But $|x|=||x||$, so the condition $|x|<\delta(\varepsilon)$ is equivalent to $||x||<\delta(\varepsilon)$; so it is true that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $x\in(-a,a)\setminus{0}$, $||x||<\delta(\varepsilon)\implies |f(|x|)-l|<\epsilon$.

This (I believe) mean that $\lim_{|x|\to 0} f(|x|)=l$; letting $|x|=r$, it is $\lim_{r \to 0} f(r)=l$. Since (I believe) the variable in the limit is dummy, this means $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=l$.

I've written "I believe" in the steps I'm not sure about. My first impressions in trying to recognize my mistakes is that probably I'm using wrong the definition of limit or the theorem of change of variables in limits. Thanks to anyone who wants to help me.

Comment: How about $f(x) = sgn(x)$. Then $f(|x|) \equiv 1 \to 1$ however the limit at zero of $f(x)$ is $-1$ from the left and $1$ from the right ie limit dne

Comment: @fGDu94: Thank you for your counter-example, however the questions is about the reasoning of the proof (hope I don't sound rude).

Comment: the problem is that $r=|x|>0$ so it is still a limit only from the right and not the left. A limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = l$ dictates that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) = l$

Comment: The error is in the "*this (I believe) mean...*" step. Let $g(x) = |x|$, then that step uses as justification that $g$ has a limit at $0$, and $f \circ g$ has a limit at $0$. But this does not imply in general that $f$ itself has a limit at $g(0)=0$, as the counterexamples show.

Comment: Now I get what I was missing; thanks fGDu94 and dxiv)